# Accesing variables in a thread that are being modified in the main program

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm creating a communication program to make a raspberry send me information to the computer. This information will need to be manipulated by other threads. So, in the main thread, I'm actually initializing the server and so on, and manipulating the variable, and in the secondary thread, I'm manipulating the data.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
import sys # Necessaty to insert the path of files that are in other folders
from communication_class import Server
import pickle
import threading
import time

sys.path.append('/home/pablo/Desktop/MY_THESIS/MasterThesisFiles_AR/measurement_processing/')

import filtering

computer = Server() # Needs to be initialized before-hand so it can be used in the 
computer.ChangePort(5020)

def DataEvaluation(n_var, n_states):
    print("Inside Data Evaluation")
    while True:
        print(computer.data)
        #time.sleep(1)


data_thread = threading.Thread(target = DataEvaluation, args = (9, 5))

computer.create_socket()
computer.create_server()
computer.start(computer.handle_readings)
```

The problem is that the data_thread isn't doing what it says, or at least it doesn't print any information (this is, the `print(computer.data)` and the `print("Inside Data Evaluation")` don't appear to be executed). Are they being executed, but because they are in other threads, they don't appear, or what is going on?

Comment: From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html): _"Once a thread object is created, its activity must be started by calling the thread’s `start()` method."_

Comment: You need to [`start()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start) threads after creating them. Also note that you need to somehow manage potentially concurrent access to `computer.data`—perhaps with a [`threading.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock).

Comment: @martineau should I manage it even if only in one of the threads is the variable being modified and in the other, the reading is done in one command?

Comment: Shared data that could be accessed by more than one thread at the same time needs to manage that access to prevent problems. Some data structures, like `Queue`s do that themselves, but it needs to be added to most other types.